# Bind vs Arrow Function when passing onChange props (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When we pass an arrow function to an event handler i.e. `onClick={() => myFunction()}`, we are causing un-necessary re-renders since this is a function definition.

Instead, should `onClick={myFunction.bind(this)}` be used instead of the arrow function whenever we call a function on an event handler and want access to `this`? Since it is only using a reference to the function, we are not causing a re-render each time.

Is the above understanding correct? If so, why would we ever use an arrow function as an event handler prop? It seems that ever since the introduction of ES6, using .bind like we do here is not usually recommended, but since it would not cause unnecessary re-renders shouldn't this be the best practice?

Comment: What is `myFunction`? Does it even use `this`? Doesn't look like it, because your arrow function doesn't contain a method call. You probably should do just `onClick={myFunction}`!

Comment: A new function is created for `myFunction.bind(this)`, too. The difference is when you're _not_ creating a new function in the render, e.g., you either `bind` in the ctor, or you use an arrow function property, and write `onClick={myFunction}`.

Comment: I don't think that `onClick={() => myFunction()}` itself causes rerenders since it isn't manipulating state. However, on ever rerender, the anonymous function will be created again. (Think: If the function definition itself caused rerenders, wouldn't it just be an infinite loop of rerendering and never load?)

Comment: "*we are causing un-necessary re-renders since this is a function definition.*" - actually no, this is largely just a myth. It's only necessary to use `useCallback` if any re-rendering in the child component actually depends on function equality (e.g. a memoised value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since it is only using a reference to the function, we are not causing a re-render each time

You're wrong.

The `bind` method returns a new function (so will trigger a re-render).

---

To avoid re-renders, make use of the `useCallback` hook.

Or, since you don't appear to be making use of `this` inside `myFunction` (otherwise `() => myFunction()` would break it), just pass `myFunction` itself without creating a new function.

```
onClick={myFunction}
```

Comment: So, how do we add custom parameter to this function call? I want to call this method, but I will add a parameter to it

Comment: @Sahin — You can find the [ask a new question page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).